# Flutter: How to display multiple pieces of data from the same function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app that displays all it's text from a database for translation purposes. Currently, I am testing how to display the text from my SQL database.

I have two functions which I use to display the text:

```
  final String displayUrl = 'https://fourieristic-thousa.000webhostapp.com/display.test.php?action=display';
  String text = "";
  String test = "";
  bool isLoaded = false;

  Future fetchData(String test) async {
    var result = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(displayUrl),
      body: {
        "test": test,
      }
    );
    isLoaded = true;
    text = (result.body);
    print("fetchData has been called. This is the data:");
    print(text);
    return text;
  }

  displayText() {
    if(isLoaded) {
      print("displayText has been called");
      return Text(text);
    } else {
      print("displayText has no data");
      return Container(); // an empty container.
    }
  }
```

Next, I use these Containers to attempt to display seperate pieces of text:

```
              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetchData(test = "one"),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData){
                      print("Data is being displayed for 'one'");
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: displayText(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      print("Data is not yet available");
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetchData(test = "test"),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData){
                      print("Data is being displayed for 'test'");
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: displayText(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      print("Data is not yet available");
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
```

When I start up the application. The page displays two containers of text. The only problem is that both pieces of text are the same as the last request [as shown here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyuyg.png)
("one" should return "two" and "test" should return "oke")

[Here's a screenshot of the console for clarity:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn04y.png)

So my question would be: How do I display both Containers with their respective data? Instead of showing the data of the latest input twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you `displayText()` you are returning a text widget using a `text` local class property. This value is always gets updated when you call the api. And all your widget use this same value. You need to build the `Text()` widget with different value.

Here is the working code:

```
  displayText(String text) {
    if(isLoaded) {
      print("displayText has been called");
      return Text(text);
    } else {
      print("displayText has no data");
      return Container(); // an empty container.
    }
  }
```

And display the value in Future builder:

```
Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(test = "one"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            print("Data is being displayed for 'one'");
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: displayText(snapshot.data),
            );
          } else {
            print("Data is not yet available");
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(test = "test"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            print("Data is being displayed for 'test'");
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: displayText(snapshot.data),
            );
          } else {
            print("Data is not yet available");
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Hello! I have tried using the code you provided. I understand what it is trying to accomplish, but when I run the app with this code, I seem to get an error from the url that provides me the data: 
"<br />
I/flutter (11205): <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in <b>/storage/ssd5/590/17197590/public_html/display.test.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
I/flutter (11205): <br />
I/flutter (11205): <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=8734 in <b>/storage/ssd5/590/17197590/public_html/display.test.php</b> on line <b>8</b>
"

Comment: I previously left a comment explaining I got an error from my hosted database. That does not seem to be an issue anymore. Your code has solved the problem.
Thank you very much ^^

Comment: My pleasure! @StefanBakker

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in below line:

```
text = (result.body);
```

You are saving results of both calls to fetchData() in same variable, and this variable is used to display text in container. The build method when called will show the last existing value of this variable. You either need to save the values in different variables, or use a list to save the values of each call on certain index.

Comment: My goal is to create a universal function that can be infinitely used. Putting the data in specific variabels would make that quite difficult. I think using a list would be the way to go. When I do this, how would I pick the specific index that I need? 

When I start up the application it seems to be random which value comes out first. One time it's "oke", the other time it's "two". Is there a way to ensure the values to be in the same order every time?

Comment: @Stefan Bakker Functions work best when they *return* the value of interest and don't have side-effects (such as reassigning or mutating member variables).  Your "universal" function shouldn't be assigning to any non-local variables at all; that should be the responsibility of its callers.

Comment: @jamesdlin that is a good point. I'll try to find a way to make that work

Comment: You can return a value from fetchData save it in text and send it as argument to display function. This way each call of display function will have different argument. The Text widget should display the argument provided.